# Windows 8 task manager, on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-8-preview, task-manager

As the MSDN Blog explained in great detail, the Windows 8 Task Manager is a big leap from the Windows 7, Vista (and especially the XP)version.

Is there a way for me to **run** the **Windows 8 Task Manager** on my **Windows 7** computer?

Assuming I had the program, **would it run properly**?

**Where** could I get **just** the Task Manager?

Comment: How about copying TaskMgr.exe from the Windows 8 machine? Have you tried that? Or anything? :)

Comment: @techie007 I've tried looking it up... several detailed Google searches...  I can't find a site that's hosting it, nor can I find a forum that says that it's possible.

Comment: This is just impossible anyways.

Comment: Can you please source this.

Comment: Hosting it would be illegal.  How about installing Win8, and copying it to your Win7 machine?  Are you actually trying this, or do you just want opinions and/or someone else to try it for you? :)

Comment: Why not give Process Explorer a try?

Comment: @VirMatrix: It's only impossible in your mind. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is **NOT** possible as Microsoft always makes the windows Component just-for-it, Like you can not run Windows 7 Task Manager on Windows XP, You can not run Windows 8 Task Manager in Windows 7. This is something like built for native environment. This question was also asked on many places on the internet, such as [here (Microsoft Forum)](http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/whatforum/thread/60706a4a-c421-47eb-93a5-bcd2cad631a4) and [here](http://www.sevenforums.com/customization/221406-windows-8-task-manager-windows-7-how.html). There is a look-alike task manager [here](http://www.askvg.com/get-windows-8-look-like-metro-task-manager-in-windows-xp-vista-and-7/?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed:%20AskVG%20%28AskVG%29&utm_content=Google%20Reader) (this is not a complete task manager).

If you are to find one, please also give it to me as I was also trying to achieve this.

**Edit**: Just found another software named [Process Hacker](http://processhacker.sourceforge.net/), Its quite similar to Windows 8 Task Manager.

Answer (score 3):

Try [process explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) as well. It can replace the default task manager and it has win 8 style graphs as well, including GPU monitoring.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe give [Process Hacker](http://processhacker.sourceforge.net/) a try instead.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with [Akshat's answer](https://superuser.com/a/439768/22177), however in terms of alternatives there's also **[Resource Monitor](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/closer-windows-resource-monitor/)** which comes packaged with Windows 7 (and 8).

It is more detailed than the standard stock task managers, you can also open Resource Monitor from the task managers via the *Performance* tab.

[image: Resource monitor]

Answer (score 0):

He's WRONG, you get the Windows 8 Task Manager here: http://www.askvg.com/get-windows-8-look-like-metro-task-manager-in-windows-xp-vista-and-7/

DIRECT LINK: http://www.deviantart.com/download/300826389/windows_8_metro_task_manager_for_xp__vista_and_7_by_vishal_gupta-d4z3r4l.zip

You can just run the .exe file, you don't even need to install anything. It requires .Net framework to work.

ARTICLE: http://www.howtogeek.com/129335/use-a-windows-8-like-task-manager-in-windows-7-vista-and-xp/

p.s. it's not fully featured, however. If you want a fully-featured clone, try Process Hacker here: processhacker sourceforge net

Comment: Not windows 8 task manager, but 3rd party utility & not full featured.