# Windows 8 Task Manager in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, task-manager

I am using Windows 7. I do not like the way that the Task Manager looks, it is ugly compared to that of Windows 8. How can I replace my Task Manager from Windows 7 by that of Windows 8?

[image]
<sup>**The nice looking task manager in Windows 8**</sup>

Comment: You will be unable to replace it. People actually want the Windows 8 task manager on Windows 7 and that also is not possible. http://superuser.com/questions/439757/windows-8-task-manager-on-windows-7?rq=1  You can also replace the task manager with Process Explorer if you want http://superuser.com/questions/499438/windows-7-8-restore-default-task-manager?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Process Hacker](http://processhacker.sourceforge.net/) which looks a bit like the new Taskmgr of Windows 8 and offers much more features:

[image]

On [neowin someone posted a tool called **DBCTaskman**](http://www.neowin.net/forum/topic/1149964-a-windows-8-like-task-manager-for-windows-7-work-in-progress/) which tries to emulate the Win8 taskmgr:

[image]